# Grouping/joining columns in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**UPDATE**

I solved it my self using:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

I updated the code below if anyone need to do the same and lands here.

I have a small MySQL database where I'm Searching for users

```
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid
FROM kunde
INNER JOIN $bartype ON ($bartype.brugerid = kunde.id)
WHERE  $bartype.barid ='$barid[Barid]' AND
    (email LIKE '%$keyword%') OR
    (fornavn LIKE '%$keyword%') OR
    (efternavn LIKE '%$keyword%') OR
    (CONCAT_WS(' ', fornavn, efternavn) LIKE '%$keyword%')
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Now my search function works, but only for either `'%$keyword%' LIKE fornavn or '%$keyword%' LIKE efternavn or '%$keyword%' LIKE email`.

So I would like to group the LIKE results so that when searching for "fornavn efternavn" in one string it would still show up results from these 2 columns that are in the same row.

Does this make sense? And is it possible to modify my SQL statement to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you heard about SQL injection?

Comment: you're mixing `and` and `or`, which means you're probably running into an order-of-operations pitfall. most likely that's being interpreted as `(a AND b) or c or d or e`. as well, I hope you've properly sanitized/escaped $keyword and $barid, otherwise you're in for a world of hurt when someone hits you with an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: 2 Questions: 1) Why do you have identical tables for each bar type, rather than a single table with a `bartype` column?  2) When you say "fornavin efternavn", is that a phrase that you would like to split into 2 keywords to search on, or is that a list of the matching columns you're looking to search on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you would like, you might want to try a `UNION` statement.  A union statement will take results from one query and add it into the results from another query while preserving the order (in my example, results having the email will come first, followed by fornavn, followed by efternavn).  Doing it this way will also eliminate your `AND/OR` logic that might be preventing search results from appearing.

```
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid
FROM kunde
INNER JOIN $bartype ON ($bartype.brugerid = kunde.id)
WHERE  $bartype.barid ='$barid[Barid]' AND
    email LIKE '%$keyword%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid
FROM kunde
INNER JOIN $bartype ON ($bartype.brugerid = kunde.id)
WHERE  $bartype.barid ='$barid[Barid]' AND
    fornavn LIKE '%$keyword%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid
FROM kunde
INNER JOIN $bartype ON ($bartype.brugerid = kunde.id)
WHERE  $bartype.barid ='$barid[Barid]' AND
    efternavn LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

On a side note, dynamic SQL like this is ripe for SQL injection.  May I suggest you to look into [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**UPDATE**

After your comment, here is an updated query that may be able to perform both searches at once for you:

```
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid
FROM kunde
INNER JOIN $bartype ON ($bartype.brugerid = kunde.id)
WHERE  $bartype.barid ='$barid[Barid]' AND
    email LIKE '%$keyword%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid
FROM kunde
INNER JOIN $bartype ON ($bartype.brugerid = kunde.id)
WHERE  $bartype.barid ='$barid[Barid]' AND
    fornavn + ' ' + efternavn LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - Actually I did look into UNION but never got it to work probably. Now it does. But still if I am searching for the keyword of "fornavn" and "efternavn" in one string "fornavn efternavn" it does not give me back any result. Searching for only fornavn or efternavn alone does give me results. So I was thinking if there is a way to join/group these 2 collums, and search for a match.

Comment: @Bolli Can you explain a little more about what you mean?  `fornavn` and `efternavn` are fields in your table.  Do you mean you want to enter a search string like this?  `value1 value2`?

Comment: Yes - and I'm sorry if I'm being unclear.
Let me try again.

Fornavn and Efternavn means frontname and lastname. With my SQL above, when searching for say "Jennifer Lopez" nothing shows up, but searching for "Jennifer" alone would bring her op or "Lopez" will also work. Now I also want to be able to search for "Jennifer Lopez" or like you say Value1 Value2.

Is this more clear?

Comment: @Bolli Look at my updated answer.  It might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Kyle - I also found another way, I updated my first post.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bolli You are welcome.  If I may make one suggestion, you may want to wrap your like statements in `()`.  Currently, your search is looking for an email that matches the keyword or something that matches your other lookups. `WHERE $bartype.barid = '$barid[Barid]' AND (LOOKUP STATEMENTS)`